# Solve Limit indeterminate Form using taylor Expansion

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

[image]
[image]

***It seems that the only way to remove the indeterminate form is to find equivalent of all the functions that pose the problem using taylor Expantion with the right order which is 3 in this case so we have***

Taylor expansion for sqrt(1 + log(1+x) is

[image]

And for sinx ^2:
[image]

And so on to find a simplified function that goes to 0 can we use hopital rule here?

Comment: You did not mentioned the function for which there is an indeterminate form.

Comment: Oh yes sorry ,  i'm gonna fix that

Comment: I tried using hopital,  another indeterminate form.

Comment: Using Taylor it is quite straightforward with third order. You want to use l'Hospital specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using $\ln(1+x) = x - x^2/2 + \cdots,$ you have $$\sqrt{1 + \ln(1+x)} = 1 + 1/2(x - x^2/2+\cdots) -1/8(x+\cdots)^2 + \cdots = 1 + \frac{1}{2}x - \frac{3}{8}x^2+\cdots \tag 1$$ 
and 
$$ 1 - \cos x - e^{x/2} = 1 - (1 - x^2/2+\cdots ) -(1+x/2 + x^2/8+\cdots) =
-\frac{x}{2} + \frac{3}{8}x^2+\cdots \tag 2$$

$$ \sin^2 x = x^2 + \cdots \tag 3$$

adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ and using $(3)$, you get $$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\ln(1+x) +  1 - \cos x - e^{x/2}}{\sin^2x} = 0.$$

Comment: $\sin^2 x$ generally means $(\sin x)^2$.

Comment: @GFauxPas, not that it makes a difference here. but i have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that after L'Hopitals once, you get another indeterminate form. But if you use L'Hopitals a second time, you get $\dfrac 0 2$.

I recommend evaluating $\dfrac {\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dx^2} \left({1 + \ln(1 + x)}\right)^{1/2}$ on its own so you don't make an algebra mistake, like I did the first one or two times. I'll let you confirm my algebra.

Comment: You're right, there is not indeterminate form in the second derivative. And it is equal 0/2 , I just checked that , thank you all